# Can I develop an iOS application with Rhodes platform in Ubuntu environment?

Tags: ios, ubuntu, ios-simulator, rhodes

I need to develop an application for the iOS platform. I do not have a Mac and want to use the Ubuntu operating system for this. Can I set up a development environment for this purpose on Ubuntu? If yes, then will I also have the simulator to test the iOS application in Ubuntu?

I know that I can create Android based application on Rhodes with Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html), you can't.

> **What are the requirements for developing with the iOS SDK and Xcode?**
>   To develop with the iOS SDK and Xcode, you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later and you must be registered as an Apple Developer.

Also take a look at the [Rhodes Application Building instructions](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build.print).

> iPhone/iPad versions of Rhodes apps must be built on Macintosh computers or on rhohub.com. The instructions below describe how to do this from either the Macintosh Xcode development environment or from the command line on your local Macintosh.

Answer (score 0):

No, developing applications for iOS is only possible on Mac OS-based computers.